# Is there a live PhoneGap harnessing web application example?

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

Short version:
Are there any web sites people have developed that harness PhoneGap functionality that are available on the web?

Long version:
PhoneGap allows developers to package a web site inside a native app. It also allows developers to have a PhoneGap webview embedded as part of their application. They can then point this PhoneGap integrated webview at any url, and use it like a browser.
I cannot develop web sites myself so I want to know if there are any web sites on the internet that use PhoneGap features.

Thanks

Comment: Phonegap can only be used inside native Apps. You can't use Phonegap with a WebApp.

Comment: Wrong. Web content that harnesses the PhoneGap api is usually deployed with a native app that uses PhoneGap but there is no reason a live website can't use the PhoneGap api.

Answer (score 1):

Not wrong. In order to access the Phonegap API the Phonegap App must be installed on the device. The content inside the App can point to a website, that's correct. But that does not change the fact that you need to download and install the App first.
I have two Phonegap Apps in the Apple App Store so I know what I am speaking of.

Comment: My apologies, I should have said "web sites" instead of "web apps"
I have edited the question to make it clearer.
To expand further - I have a PhoneGap app on my device and what I am looking for is a website that makes PhoneGap api calls... so that I can show off my app, which essentially is a PhoneGap enabled browser.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap has a section on their website dedicated to mobile apps that were built using it:
http://phonegap.com/apps

Comment: Either you did not read or understand the question fully.

I don't want to download a native app that uses PhoneGap, I want to know if there are any web apps on the internet that use the PhoneGap api. To that end I want a url to some web content, not a downloadable app. Thanks for your help nonetheless.